# docker swarm mongodb task non-zero exit 252

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy a Docker Swarm stack from a Docker Compose file and I'm having issues initiating a MongoDB service.

Every time I want to, the following error occurs:

```
"task: non-zero exit (252)"
```

It's important to note that this error occurs in Docker for Windows. In the Linux version, it deploys fine.

Comment: What do you see with a docker service logs [serviceName]

Comment: @Kilian I ran the command and this is the error line: `2018-06-07T15:33:00.956+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script @(shell eval):1:30`.There's no indication about which script this is.